# How to use a button created in XIB custom view to control setContentOffset in viewController.swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiscrollview, xib, ibaction

I followed this tutorial to create a Snapchat-Like Menu: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_daE3IL_1s

In short, the idea was to create custom views with XIB, and add them into a scrollview.

I would like to add a "back" button to one of the custom views so that the scrollview will automatically scroll back to its initial view when the button is tapped. The Idea I had was to write a code inside the custom view's IBAction function to call UIScrollview's content offset delegate function.

the following is the code in View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
//I'm naming the Scroll View as "scrollView"
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
    didSet{
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var v1 : View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)
    var v2 : View2 = View2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)

    self.addChild(v1)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(v1.view)
    v1.didMove(toParent: self)

    self.addChild(v2)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(v2.view)
    v1.didMove(toParent: self)

    var v2Frame : CGRect = v2.view.frame
    v2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    v2.view.frame = v2Frame

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 2, height: self.view.frame.height)

   // self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(self.view.frame.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height)
}
```

}

The following ht the code in View2:

```
class View2: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var buttonHome: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


@IBAction func buttonHomeAction(_ sender: Any) {
    //how to access scrollview.setContentOffset from ViewController to scroll the view back to the first view?
}
```

So my question is how to access scrollview.setContentOffset from ViewController to scroll the view back to the first view? Am I on the right track? Or are there any alternative methods where I can tap a button and scroll the view back to its first page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two good options here:

1) Hold a weak reference in `View2` of the `scrollView`. in `View2` add:

```
weak var scrollView: UIScrollView?
```

and in `ViewController`, after `view2` creation add:

```
view2.scrollView = self.scrollView
```

now, in `buttonHomeAction` you'll have access to the scrollView.

2) If you are familiar with Apple's delegation pattern, you can add a delegate, which can be a weak reference of the presenting view controller.

Create a protocol for the delegate, using named by the view holds the delegate. so, in this case: `View2Delegate`
and add a method that describes the action.

```
protocol View2Delegate: AnyObject {
    func buttonTapped()
}
```

so, in `View2` add:

```
weak var delegate: View2Delegate?
```

and in `ViewController`, after `view2` creation add:

```
view2.delegate = self
```

now, in `ViewController` implement the protocol method and access scrollView:

```
extension ViewController: View2Delegate {
    func buttonTapped() {
        // access scrollView as self.scrollView
    }
}
```